# MATLAB: Save multiple tables in Excel using a while loop

Tags: excel, matlab, while-loop

I have the following while loop in which an image is read and analyzed, then the results are saved in a table, that is saved in an Excel worksheet. I initially did this code for one single image/table, then realized I need to develop it for n images.

I basically want the results to be saved in the same Excel worksheet without overwriting, ideally the tables are vertically separated by an empty row.

Here's my effort as for now:

```
while(1)
...
%code code code
...
message = sprintf('Do you want to save the results in an Excel 
worksheet?');
reply = questdlg(message,'Run Program?','OK','Cancel', 'OK');
if strcmpi(reply, 'Cancel')
% User canceled so exit.
return;
end


% Table creation. 
% code code code
% Saving table to Excel

T = table(Diameter,BandWidth,n1,n2,P1,P2,Damage,...
'RowNames',Band);
filename = 'Results.xlsx';
writetable(T, filename, 'Sheet',1, 'Range', 'A1','WriteRowNames',true);

% Create a while loop to save more experiments to the Excel worksheet.

promptMessage = sprintf('Do you want to process another photo?');
button = questdlg(promptMessage, 'Continue', 'Continue', 'Cancel', 
'Continue');
if strcmpi(button, 'Cancel')
break;
end
end
```

If it can help you to get an idea, each table is a 6x8.

Comment: Can't you just add rows to your results table and write to excel once the processing is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to your while loop, declare a cell array to hold the table that you will eventually write to an excel file.

```
cellArrayOfTableToBeWritten = {};
```

Also prior to the loop, define a cell array that will serve as a blank row.

```
rowWidth = 8;
blankrow = repmat({''},1,rowWidth);
```

Where you currently write the table, instead add what you would have written to the cell array with a blank row at the bottom.

```
cellArrayOfTableToBeWritten = [cellArrayOfTableToBeWritten;
                               T.Properties.VariableNames; 
                               table2cell(T); 
                               blankrow];
```

Once your while loop is done, write the combined cell array to a file as an excel file.

```
xlswrite(filename, cellArrayOfTableToBeWritten);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Your code gives me an error where I write to the cell array (I commented the writetable bit). The error is: `Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.`

Comment: Good it works now. I had to download a xlwrite function to write into the Excel because I'm on a Macbook. Thanks and I'll accept your answer.